# The present perfect when talking about the future

Tags: scoping, time-reference

Here is a piece from a video game. A writer is planning to start a book series called *The Paths of the Doomstones*. A correspondent of the local newspaper, the Courier, is interviewing her.

> She assured the Courier that she **will** fill the Doomstones series with the lusty and colorful characters **we've** come to know and love.

We are talking about a future event, but why is the present perfect used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, the characters (or the general type of characters) are already known:

- Either she's writing a *new* book in an *already established* series
- or she has written *other* books and the newspaper refers to the colorful etc. characters *in these*.